# In WPF projects, how to prevent WCF requests to be serviced by the UI thread?

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf

Long delays in my WCF service implementation are blocking my WPF UI. When I make the methods run in a new thread the problem is solved, but I can't answer my clients synchronously this way. I think WCF is using the UI thread. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decorate your WPF Hosted WCF Service with

```
[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately since I introduced this line to my code, sometimes I get a hard to debug NullReferenceException coming from the System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.MoveToPosition method. The stack trace doesn't include a single method I wrote, only Framework's methods.